# How to use a list of vectors in alternation (regular expressions)

Tags: r, regex, alternation

Is it possible to parse a vector of character strings to an alternation element in a regular expression? For example:

```
pattern <- "^This\\s(*alternation element*)\\srocks\\."
Animals <- c("cow","dog","cat")
```

So if I would then parse "Animals" to the regular expression it would result in:

```
pattern <- "^This\\s(*cow|dog|cat*)\\srocks\\."
```

It should basically work like `or1()` from the `rebus` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `paste0` to generate your regex :

```
paste0('^This\\s(', paste0(Animals, collapse = "|"), ')\\ssrocks\\.')
#[1] "^This\\s(cow|dog|cat)\\ssrocks\\."
```

Note than in R, you need to use double backslash (`\\`).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("^Thi\\s(%s)\\ssrocks\\.", paste(Animals, collapse="|"))
#[1] "^Thi\\s(cow|dog|cat)\\ssrocks\\."
```